# Is it possible to port a windows phone 7.0 silverlight class library to windows 10 mobile

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, windows-10-mobile

I have a windows phone class library that is built for windows phone 7.0(coded in c#). Is it possible to port the same class library to windows 10 mobile sdk?. Or, do I need to write the entire class library from scratch to support windows 10 mobile.

Comment: What APIs are you using in your library? WP7 UI components/controls?

Comment: WP7 UI components, Making http calls, XML parsing, I/O operations, etc,,,

Comment: You dont need to rewrite it from scratch but porting the code may be a little bit more time consuming...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to port it, but not in an automated way.

- UI components should be relatively easy, as long as not a lot of
  third party controls such as Telerik for Windows Phone were used.
  Third party libraries need to have been ported to the WinRT platform
  (or UWP, as it it called now) as well, which is not always the case.
  Most of the XAML can be re-used, but some namespaces, events and properties are named differently (eg: Tap becomes Tapped).
  Some layouts may need to be reworked a bit due to a different approach in scaling (Silverlight scaled everything up, as it pretended a screen is always 480px wide).
- HTTP calls: This is probably going to have to change a lot, depending
  on how they were implemented in your WP7 library. Webclient no longer
  exits in WinRT, HttpClient or creating your own HttpWebRequest is the
  way to go. Since WP7 apps did not have async/await by default, I
  would suggest rewriting this part.
- XML parsing: This should be compatible (maybe some small syntax changes)
- I/O operations: Probably massive changes. WP7 used the Isolated Storage mechanism, which has been replaced. Capturing images with the CameraCaptureTask, and basically all use of sensors will have to be rewritten.
- Local Database is not longer supported. Use Sqlite if you want to use a database in your app.
- The application lifecycle is also completely different in WinRT. Pages in the backstack are not cached automatically and a lot of events in a page work differently, or might not occur at the same time as they were in Silverlight applications

for more info: [Move from Windows Phone Silverlight to UWP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt149138.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Most of UI elements has changed from wp7.0 to Windows10. It will have to completely rewrite. The same applies to WP 7.0 API.

---

If you has portable library then the problems should be much less